# SqlCommand Parameter Not Contained In Collection

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred 
in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An SqlParameter with ParameterName 'catStart' 
is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.
```

When running this code:

```
var command = new SqlCommand();
command.Parameters.Add("@startSku", SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters.Add("@endSku", SqlDbType.VarChar);

command.Parameters.Add("@catStart", SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters.Add("@catEnd", SqlDbType.VarChar);

command.Parameters.Add("@active1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters.Add("@active2", SqlDbType.VarChar);

command.Parameters["@startSku"].Value = 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(startSku) 
    ? SqlHelpers.MinString 
    : startSku;

command.Parameters["@endSku"].Value = 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(endSku) 
    ? SqlHelpers.MaxString 
    : endSku;

command.Parameters[@"catStart"].Value = 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(startCategory)
    ? SqlHelpers.MinString
    : startCategory;

command.Parameters[@"catEnd"].Value = 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(endCategory)
    ? SqlHelpers.MaxString
    : endCategory;

command.Parameters[@"active1"].Value = isActive;
command.Parameters[@"active2"].Value = checkIsActive ? isActive : !isActive;
```

The exception is thrown on:

```
command.Parameters[@"catStart"].Value = 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(startCategory)
    ? SqlHelpers.MinString
    : startCategory;
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why. I've tried creating the parameter independently and then adding to the collection. I've tried some different data types. I tried renaming them. I don't understand why it's being fussy.

Comment: Just a typo... vote to close

Comment: Oh man. I must have looked at that a dozen times. The literal doesn't even look wrong because I use it in so many other places. Vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"@catStart"` instead of `@"catStart"` and in other places too.

Answer (score 0):

your parameters are not correctly formatted. Like,

```
command.Parameters[@"catStart"].Value =
```

should be

```
command.Parameters["@catStart"].Value = 
command.Parameters["@catEnd"].Value = 
command.Parameters["@active1"]
command.Parameters["@active2"]
command.Parameters["@catStart"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Format is incorrect. It should be

```
command.Parameters["@catStart"].Value =

command.Parameters["@catEnd"].Value = 

command.Parameters["@active1"]
```